# Is this sentence structure correct?

Tags: meaning

> Lift the device or system should the stunt person become
>   misaligned during the fall.

What does it mean? "fall" means the stunt action of falling. Does it mean that "Lift the device or system that could make the stunt person become misaligned during the fall"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is about preposition placement. The preposition phrase `during the fall` follows `the stunt person become misaligned` because this is where it sounds most grammatically correct. Look through the following examples, and see which arrangement sounds the best:

```
At the end of the sentence
```

> `Lift the device or system should the stunt person become misaligned during the fall.`
>
> `during the fall` refers to when the stunt person is falling.

```
After stunt person
```

> `Lift the device or system should the stunt person during the fall become misaligned.`
>
> `during the fall` refers to when the stunt person is falling.

```
After device or system
```

> `Lift the device or system during the fall should the stunt person become misaligned.`
>
> `during the fall` could refer to you or the stunt person.

```
Beginning of sentence.
```

> `During the fall, lift the device or system should the stunt person become misaligned.`
>
> `during the fall` could refer to you or the stunt person.

Answer (score 0):

“Should” basically means “if” in a construction like this:

> If the stunt person becomes misaligned during the fall, lift the device or system.

And yes, the original sentence is grammatical.